# My 94 Honda Civic..which is a manual..will crank but not start... but it will clutch off

Tags: engine, honda, starting, civic, manual-transmission

My 94 Honda Civic..which is a 5 speed manual..will crank but not start..It will clutch off and runs and drives well after that. I have to pump the clutch several times before it will even start to crank.  I have changed out both of the switches on the clutch housing and even joined the wires together of the lowest switch together. I have changed the battery, fuel pump, fuel relay(the one that mounts near the hood latch), spark plugs, ignition coil, distributor cap and rotor button, and the electronic portion of the ignition switch. Once it jumps off it runs well despite a little surging when it idles( I'll ask for help with the idling problem after I get passed this).

Comment: Does the cranking sound normal (except that it never actually starts of course)? Just to be sure, when you say "clutch off" you mean rolling the car down a hill or pushing it and popping the clutch to get the engine to turn over, is that right?  And thanks for adding to the site, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Get the schematics for your car and trace out the starting circuit with a test light. Wondering in the clutch is 'false positive' and the issue is actually somewhere else, or if the clutch is moving a wire.

Your clutch switch will not allow the starter to turn, so if the starter is turning, it is not related to the clutch switch.  Your issue sounds to be related to spark or fuel.  This sounds like bad grounds to me, but it is hard to be sure without poking around with a test light.

Answer (score 0):

@paulster.. Yes.. The start sounds normal and yes jump off refers to getting a rolling start and Poppin the clutch.

I do still have to pump the clutch several times before it will turn over..